# Waterline replacement

Tags: plumbing, kitchen-sink

I have replaced my sink with a farm sink and upgraded my faucet and garbage disposal.  However,  when replacing the waterline,  I can't remove it off the line.  one end had a twist, but the end that connects directly to the water will not twist off, and I'm unsure how to remove it.  Has anyone seen this type of flexible line used before and know how to remove it?

[image]

Comment: That's a very small picture. Can you get a close up of the grey fitting with some of the flex line to the right and a bit of the hard line below, please? You can [edit] the new pic into your question. Also what country are you in? That doesn't look like anything I'm familiar with in the US. Knowing the locale can help with figuring it out.

Comment: Yes, I will replace the picture now.  Thank you for your assistance.  I'm in the US,  in Georgia.

Comment: I think it is bought like that as in one piece, the hose and valve.